# How to create a function that works generically on an Array as well as an Option

Tags: scala

I would like to create a generic function that works for both an Array as an Option:

```
val numbers = Array(1, 2, 3)
val numberO: Option[Int] = Some(4)

def addOnes(numbers: ???[Int]) = numbers.map(_+1)

addOnes(numbers)
addOnes(numberO)
```

Right now I have a separate function for each structure

```
def addOnesForArray(numbers: Array[Int]) = numbers.map(_+1)
def addOnesForOption(numberO: Option[Int]) = numberO.map(_+1)

addOnesForArray(numbers)
addOnesForOption(numberO)
```

So basically I need a superclass of Array and Option that has the functor and monad methods map, flatMap, filter, ...

Comment: should this work on just those two or on anything which has a map, flatmap etc.?

Comment: Did you try any library (cats, scalaz) which provide functor instances?

Comment: Hi Assaf ideally the more generic the better although for now I only need a solution for Array and Option

Comment: Hi Yuval, no I haven't tried it and I would like to stay away from scala "advanced" as long as I can ;-) but if that's the only solution I might go for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use structural typing (aka "duck typing"), with which we could say that you need literally "something with a map", written as `{ def map(): T }`. But that's a) ugly, b) uses reflection, and c) hard (note that `map(): T` is just an example; in reality you will have to match the exact signature of map, with CanBuildFrom and all that jazz).

Better way would be to reach for [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) or [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) and use category theory concepts. Just pick the least powerful abstraction that does the job. If you need just `map`, then it's a Functor. If you want to map with (curried) functions of more than one parameter, then it's an Applicative. If you also want `flatMap`, then it's a monad, etc.

Example for functor:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def addOne[F[Int]](f: F[Int])(implicit m: Functor[F]) = f.map(_ + 1)

val numbers = Array(1, 2, 3).toList
val numberO = Option(123)

addOne(numbers) // List(2, 3, 4)
addOne(numberO) // Some(124)
```

You will notice that I had to convert your array to a List because there are no typeclass instances (that I know of) for functors, applicatives, monads etc. that work on arrays. But arrays are old fashioned and invariant and really not idiomatic Scala anyway. If you get them from elsewhere, just convert them to Lists, Vectors etc. (based on your use case) and work with those from that point onwards.

Answer (score 2):

In general I agree with @slouc . If you want to make existing classes kinda extend some other trait you need typeclasses.
But in your particular case it is not required since `Option` and `Array` are both `Traversable`:

```
object Example extends App {
  def plus1(data: Traversable[Int]): Traversable[Int] = data.map(x => x + 1)

  println(plus1(Array(1, 2, 3)))
  println(plus1(Some(4)))
}
```

Comment: I agree with this, if his use case is "I need some traversable". But he said "I need the functor and monad methods". What if he wants to map a Future?

Comment: Indeed, ideally the solution should work with any functors and monads but if that means bringing in scalaz I'm happy with only the "collection-like" structures.

Comment: Indeed Traversable is a common superclass of Array and Option. Any idea how I can keep the output collection the same as the input collection?

Comment: I tried with def plus2[F <: Traversable[Int]](data: F): F = data.map(x => x + 2) but that doesn't seem to compile

Comment: @NiekBartholomeus If you need to preserve the type of output collection use solution by slouc  and don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @simpadjo you mean there is no way that by adding a type class or another simple tweak this could possibly work? Well in that case it makes sense to look at scalaz. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ NiekBartholomeus What's wrong with "bringing in Scalaz"? Perhaps it has a bit of a notorious reputation, but you can use it only for the parts you need. It's not like suddenly all your Options will have to become Maybes or whatever. The snippet I posted is self contained and does what you need, and no other part of code needs to know you're using scalaz at all.

Comment: @slouc I see your point ;-) however by adding "just a dependency" you know exactly what value it will bring right now but the cost of it (in term of maintenance, direct and indirect dependencies, complexity, ...) you will only find out in the long run, hence my initial resistance. But in this case I think the risk is worth it so I'm accepting your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Niek I agree that it's stupid to bring the whole library for a thing or two, but scalaz is full of nice things (cats too) and I'm sure you'll keep finding new interesting stuff inside as you progress. In case you're working with Futures, I would recommend turning them into Tasks as the next step ;)